# Core data with "Many to Many relationShip" crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, core-data

I can't able to add data with "Many to Many relationship"

**My code**

```
let cate2 = self.saveCategories(dict["categories"] as! Array, partyObject: party)//party is NSMAngedObjected Model

let categories = party.mutableSetValueForKey("categories")
                categories.addObjectsFromArray(cate2)
//categories is the many to many relationship between Party & Categories Entity
```

**Debug Output**

```
Printing description of cate2:
▿ 1 elements
  ▿ [0] : 1 elements
    - [0] : < apple.Categories: 0x7fbc6ad62dd0> (entity: Categories; id: 0x7fbc6ad62e80 <x-coredata:///Categories/tE393C265-31D1-4E54-92DC-425C9FCB56493> ; data: {
    "category_Name" = 1;
    parties =     (
    ); //parties in the inverse relationship with Party Entity
})

2016-05-13 12:33:49.642 apple[6456:94286] -[_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbc6ad68a40
2016-05-13 12:33:49.688 apple[6456:94286] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbc6ad68a40
```

**Edit**

```
func saveCategories(arr_categories:[AnyObject],partyObject:Party) -> [AnyObject] {


        var categories_model = [Categories]()

        if(!arr_categories.isEmpty){
        for categoryObject in arr_categories {

                let  category = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Categories",
                                                                                 inManagedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext) as! Categories
                category.category_Name = String(categoryObject)
                //category.parties = partyObject
                //category.parties = [partyObject]
                categories_model.append(category)
            }

            return categories_model
    }

        return []

            }
```

I added code for saveCategory.It will returns the array of Categories nsmangedObject Model.

**Help me to solve this**

**Thank you,**

Comment: Please provide a little more info like your coredata model describing relationship with entities and content of dict["categories"] to understand your question

Comment: @SandeepBhandari,
there is Party & Categories Entity. There is "categories & parties" many to many inverse relationship respectively.

dict["categories"] is an array of categories from server

Comment: @SandeepBhandari
is this good to understand?

Comment: May I know what exactly are you doing in method self.saveCategories ???

Comment: @SandeepBhandari
it  will return array of Category ManagedObjectModel as you see in cate2

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, is this good to understand?

Comment: Show the `saveCategories` code - it looks like `cate2` is in fact an array of arrays of Categories, not a flat array of Categories.

Comment: @pbasdf, I added code for saveCategory

Comment: You are returning an array with categories_model in it; you should just be returning categories_model.  Amend `return [categories_model]` to `return categories_model`.

Comment: @pbasdf,isn't it useful to save whole array at once?

Comment: @pbasdf I just asking that is that creat any problem if I pass whole array?

Comment: You are passing an array with an array in it.  `[categories_model]` is an array *containing* the array `categories_model`.  Just pass the array `categories_model` itself.

Comment: @pbasdf, yes I tried that one also but still getting problem like: **_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray managedObjectContext**

Comment: @NiravPatel What does the debug output look like now?

Comment: @pbasdf, Thanks for your great help!
Now I solved it successfully!